# How do i create dynamic div with data

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, web

i am using inner html for get dynamically div with sql server data. the div arrangement is not align horizontal. need to horizontal align them. please help me.thank you

```
        pnl_default.Visible = true;
        pnl_content.Visible = false;
        HtmlGenericControl html_default = new HtmlGenericControl();
        html_default.TagName = "div";

        string cmdString = ".........";


        DataTable dtSystems = OraQueryData(cmdString);
        foreach (DataRow dtRow in dtSystems.Rows)
        {
            string system_name = Convert.ToString(dtRow["Branch"]);



            var btn_system = new Button
            {
                ID = "btn_" + system_name,
                Text = system_name,

                CssClass = "myButton2"
            };

            string html = " <div class=div1> <div class= pnlback >  <div class= header> <b>" + system_name + " </b></div><div class= body> <img style= width: '50px'; height: 50px src =/Scripts/atm.png> </div><div class=footer><button  runat=server>SHOW</i></button></div></div> </ div >   <span></ span >   ";

            html_default.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(html));
            html_default.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p>"));               


        }
        Panel2.Controls.Clear();
        Panel2.Controls.Add(html_default);
```

[image]

What i need to do..
[image]

the divs are un countable... i need fill panel from divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lulitha,
test these codes and use in your div:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #dad{text-align: center;width: 100%;}
       .son{display: inline-block;padding: 0px 5px;border: 1px solid;margin:0 5px;}
</style>
<div id="dad">
    <div class="son">son</div>
    <div class="son">son</div>
    <div class="son">son</div>
    <div class="son">son</div>
    <div class="son">son</div>
</div>

<br />

<div id="dad">
    <div class="son">son</div>
    <div class="son">son</div>
    <div class="son">son</div>
    <div class="son">son</div>
</div>

<br />

<div id="dad">
    <div class="son">son</div>
    <div class="son">son</div>
    <div class="son">son</div>
</div>
```